# How to get filtered results with backbone.localStorage?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I have `events` collection the contains the following documents:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   title: 'Untitled',
   date: '01.01.2014'
}
```

I'm executing the following `fetch` query `/events/01.01.2014`

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("events"),

      initialize: function () {
         this.fetch({
             url: '/events/01.01.2015'             
         })
      }
});
```

The problem here is that collections returns all events instead for particular data (like `/01.01.2014` in the example above). How could I filter events by using Backbone.LocalStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to filter the models stored in local storage when you fetch your collection.

The filtering part can be done without a fetch , by using findAll on your store:

```
var c = new Collection();  // your collection, filled elsewhere
var store = c.localStorage; // associated localstorage
var allmodels = store.findAll(); // direct acces to the models in storage

// models having a matching date
var filtered = _.where(allmodels , {date: '01.01.2014'});
```

To filter the results after a `fetch`, you can override `Collection.sync` (heavily inspired by [Backbone.localStorage's source code](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js#L172)):

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("events"),

    sync: function(method, coll, opts) {
        var parentsync = Backbone.Collection.prototype.sync;
        opts = opts || {};

        // we're only interested in the fetch requests with a custom url
        if ((method !== "read") || (!opts.url))
            return parentsync.call(this, method, coll, opts);

        // let's pick the date in the url
        var re = /^\/events\/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})$/,
            matches = opts.url.match(re),
            date = matches && matches[1];

        // no date, no override
        if (!date)
            return parentsync.call(this, method, coll, opts);

        // the filtering described above
        var store = this.localStorage, dfd = Backbone.$.Deferred(),
            models = store.findAll();

        models = _.where(models, {date: date});

        // calling the callback and resolving the deferred
        opts.success(models);
        dfd.resolve(models);

        return dfd.promise();
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/0tyrk73s/